# Setting up facets in SOLR

Tags: solr, lucene, schema

I am using solr and I want to setup two different types of facets on my data. The first is date, so I would like it like this:

Posted:
Today
3 days
7 days
All time

Distance:
5 miles
10 miles
30 miles
100 miles

How should I be setting up faceting? It looks like something I need to edit my solr.xml or my schema.xml but it is all very confusing and the help documents boggle my mind.

Can someone who has done this before give me a bit of guidance please?

Comment: Well, this is what I am working from. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview#Facet_Indexing . It talks about adding this fq=<facet-field> but I dont have any facet fields setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`facet.query`: This parameter can be specified multiple times to indicate that multiple queries should be used as separate facet constraints. So you can do `distance:[* TO 5]`, `distance:[5 TO 10]` and you will get the individual counts.

Then there is `facet.date` and `facet.range` which may better suit you.